# Counting the elements in rows and map to column in r

Tags: r, apply

I would like summarize my data by counting the entities and create counting_column for each entity.
let say:
df:

```
id   class
1     A
1     B
1     A
1     A
1     B
1     c
2     A
2     B
2     B
2     D
```

I want to create a table like

```
id  A  B  C  D
1   3  2  1  0
2   1  2  0  1
```

How can I do this in R using **apply** function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"class"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

with(df, table(id, class))
#   class
#id  A B C D
#  1 3 2 1 0
#  2 1 2 0 1

xtabs(~ id + class, df)
#   class
#id  A B C D
#  1 3 2 1 0
#  2 1 2 0 1

tapply(rep(1, nrow(df)), df, length, default = 0)
#   class
#id  A B C D
#  1 3 2 1 0
#  2 1 2 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very strange requirement but if you insist on using `apply` then the  function `count` counts the number of rows for which `id` equals `x` and `class` equals `y`.  It is applied to every combination of `id` and `class` to get `a` using nested `apply` calls.  Finally we add the row and column names.

```
uid <- unique(DF$id)
uclass <- unique(DF$class)

count <- function(x, y, DF) sum(x == DF$id & y == DF$class)
a <- apply(matrix(uclass), 1, function(u) apply(matrix(uid), 1, count, u, DF))
dimnames(a) <- list(uid, uclass)
```

giving:

```
> a
  A B c D
1 3 2 1 0
2 1 2 0 1
```

### Note

We used this for `DF`

```
Lines <- "id   class
1     A
1     B
1     A
1     A
1     B
1     c
2     A
2     B
2     B
2     D"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```